# Append to associate array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script that iterates through a PDF file (loops over each page), and inside each page does some text manipulation. So basically two loops:

```
files = {}

#npages is the number of PDF pages in the specific file.

for n in range(npages):

    path = pdf_name + str(n + 1) + '_1.txt'

    files[int(n)] = path

    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):

        path = pdf_name + str(n + 1) + '_' + str(i + 2) + '.txt'
        files[int(n)][int(i)] = path
```

Basically, I looking on *each* PDF page, and on each page I then further do some text manipulation.

I am trying to output it like:

```
- file_page_1.pdf
  - file_page_1_col_1.pdf
  - file_page_1_col_2.pdf
file_page_2.pdf
  - file_page_2_col_1.pdf
  - file_page_2_col_2.pdf
```

However using above coes gives me below error:

```
files[int(n)][int(i)] = path
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Basically I am “just” trying to create an associate array, where the page path is the main array, and then the “sub files” on that page is the sub arrays

Comment: you should try `files[int(n)]({int(i): path})`

Comment: @P.hunter that gives me `'str' object is not callable`

Comment: my bad sorry I did a silly mistake it should be `files[int(n)].update({int(i): path})`

Comment: @P.hunter Sorry, but still not: `'str' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: sorry for my repeated mistakes in the comments section, I must've seen your code thoroughly T_T, check out my answer by the way it'll answer your problem most probably.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. Can you include a minimal example your desired result, what `files` should *look* like? what should we see with `print(files)`.

Comment: Why are you indexing your `files` by `n` but your desired output does not include these `n`? It looks more like you want your `files` to have a key of `path` and the value to be a list of subpaths? Then you can do `files[path] = []` in your first loop and then in the second loop do `subpath = pdf_name + ...` and `files[path].append(subpath)`. (not reusing variable name `path` since you need the original path name to index the dict)

Comment: @Endyd Ah, that is what I am looking for. However, how do I then iterate `files`, so I get the `path` as the the first item, and then loops over all `subpaths`, before going to the next `path`?

Comment: You can go through in a nested for loop. `for path, subpaths in files.items(): for subpath in subpaths: print(subpath)`. It should be noted that dict items are not ordered, so if you want them to be accessed in the order you inserted them, you will want to use `OrderedDict` from `collections`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the structure you're looking for is a dict that has string keys to list values.

```
files = {}

for page in range(npages):
    path = pdf_name + str(n+1) + '_1.txt'
    files[path] = []
    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):
        subpath = pdf_name + str(n + 1) + '_' + str(i + 2) + '.txt'
        files[path].append(subpath)

# For accessing items
for path, subpaths in files.items():
    # path is a string, the key in files dict
    print(path) 
    # subpaths is a list of strings, the value in files dict
    for subpath in subpaths:
        print(subpath)
```

If you want the path/subpath pairs to be returned in the order it was inserted, you can use OrderedDict instead of dict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
files = OrderedDict()
# code as above
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because `files[int(n)]` returns you `str` and not a dictionary.

as you can see from your line.

```
files[int(n)] = path
```

you are trying to achieve a dictionary behavior from a `str` object.
to carry out what you are trying to do we can do something like.

```
from collections import defaultdict

files = {}
for n in range(npages):
    path = pdf_name + str(n + 1) + '_1.txt'
    files[int(n)] = defaultdict()
    files[int(n)]['path_root'] = path

    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):
        path = pdf_name + str(n + 1) + '_' + str(i + 2) + '.txt'
        files[int(n)][int(i)] = path
```

this should give you result like:

```
|-- nth file 
|    |
|    |- path_root
|    |- child1 (0)
|    |- child2 (1)
..
```

A quick side note about `defaultdict`:

```
somedict = {}
print(somedict[3]) # KeyError

someddict = defaultdict(int) # or str
print(someddict[3]) # print int(), thus 0 (str will return you '')
```

Comment: This gives me an error `sub_path[int(n)] = defaultdict()
NameError: name 'sub_path' is not defined`

Comment: If I change it to `path`, I still get the same error as before: `'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: No worries, thanks for helping! It almost works, however the first `path` is not added to the list. This one: `path = pdf_name + str(n + 1) + '_1.txt'`

Comment: check out new edit @oliverbj, please let me know if any issues.

Comment: I don't see that you are adding the `path` in the first loop `for n in range (npages)`. You only create the defaultdict here. I need the path from both loops

Comment: @oliverbj I went over your question again and realized that some things were odd, like how `files[int(n)] = path` can have `files[int(n)][int(i)] = path` , because   `files[int(n)]` is a string and can't be indexed like this, seems like you wanted a root path and sub paths as children, let me know if this works